# Real Analysis: equivalence of a limit related statement

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that these two statements are equivalent, but moving $n$ and limit to the other side seems a little bold to me:

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty }  n\big( \sqrt{4+ \frac{1}{n} } - 2 \big)=  \frac{1}{4}  $$
is equivalent to
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty }  \big( \sqrt{4+ \frac{1}{n} } - 2 \big)= \lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty } \frac{1}{4n} = 0 $$

I just started doing my first real analysis course and was wondering if this statement of mine is true. If so, can one justify it using the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition?

Comment: The first statement is equivalent to [$\left(\sqrt{4+ \frac1n} - 2\right)\sim\frac1{4n}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis), and whenever $u_n\sim v_n$ and $v_n\to\ell,$ you can derive $u_n\to\ell.$ But the converse is false if $\ell=0$: if $\lim u_n=\lim v_n=0,$ we do not necessarily have $u_n\sim v_n.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To point out this equivalence is not a good approach to solving this limit, especially for students still coming to terms with the concept of limits, for the following reason:

Although the two statements are equivalent, since they are both *true* statements, there is no general "pattern" that can be observed or abstracted from this, that can be used to solve further problems, i.e. if it is the case that

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{c}{g(x)} 
\end{align}

It is *not* the case in general that

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x) = c
\end{align}

A good exercise for you would be to find a counter example to this statement

Comment: let g(x) = 1/ f(x) = 1/ Ax^2, c not equal to 1. taking limit of x goes to infinity results in  both side going to infinity, which makes line 1 true. but f(x)g(x)=1.